# Зарегистрировать новый тип файла и открывающую программу в linux

Tags: файлы, расширения, linux

Подскажите пожалуйста, как зарегистрировать новый("собственный") тип файла и открывающую программу (для него) в linux.

Answer (score 3):

а никак. Тут другой принцип.
Первое - посмотрите на большинство тексовых файлов-скриптов. В самом начале есть строка, которая начинается с `#!`, а дальше путь к файлу. Если этот скрипт будет иметь право на исполнение, то этот скрипт будет проинтерпретирован указанной программой. А какое у файла расширение - это абсолютно не имеет значение.

Но вот в gnome/kde/xfce - там другое дело. Там  можно привязать программы по расширениею. Начните читать с [этого](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Changing_filetype_association_via_MIME_%28%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%29). А потом гуглите на тему linux mime-type.

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрю)